# Data Type Mismatched Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i'm using VB and Access, tried to use Select Statement filtering WHERE EmployeeID equals to userInput which is an int value, but giving me an error Data type Mismatched

```
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID ='" & userInput & "' ")
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with how you construct the query when it comes to WHERE INT VALUES statement. Please help Thanks Guys.

Comment: Is EmployeeID an Integer Column?

Comment: If it is then you don't need the single-quotes: `WHERE EmployeeID = " & userInput`. Just make sure that userInput is actually a number, otherwise the query will fail - try `IsNumeric`.

Comment: Thank You Guys, it worked :). it's kinda tricky and confusing whenever we put variables in a where statement quotes and double quotes arghhh nightmare when careles. Kudos more power.

Comment: `no quotes` for **numeric** data types, `' single quote` for a **String** data types, `# ... #` **hashes** at start and end usually for **DateTime** types

Answer (score 0):

Take out the single quotes.

```
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID =" & userInput & "")
```